# POPCNT in Delphi XE/ XE2 64bit

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-xe, basm

How do I implement a count of 1-bits  within a 16/32/64bit word using the very fast Intel POPCNT instruction, under Delphi XE or XE2? Is there a library routine giving direct access to this instruction? Can someone write a demo asm section illustrating its use please?
And finally, what are the options for 64bit Delphi (no asm available)?
thanks in advance
t

Comment: asm is avaible in 64 bit Delphi as well.

Comment: I suppose it's not as simple as just writing `popcnt eax, eax` or `popcnt rax, rcx` inside an asm block, is it?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: http://www.strchr.com/crc32_popcnt has a comparison table of popcnt implementations, where a SSSE3 (`pshufb` for nibble table lookup) variant actually beats `popcnt` on some systems. Only a few %, not necessarily the same on all CPUs, and only beneficial if you do the operation for a large (100+ Bytes) amount of data. _Very fast_ is relative.

Comment: @FrankH I have tested this implementation too, since I need a very fast popcount, and I found the SSSE3 version slower by almost a magnitude, even if I use large amounts of data. I suspect an error or bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob Kennedy sugested, here you have functions for 32bit and 64bit Delphi IDE.

```
function GetBitCount(num: integer): integer;
asm
  POPCNT    eax, num
end;

function GetBitCount(num: Int64): integer;
asm
  POPCNT    rax, num
end;
```

EDIT:
This is 32bit and 64bit Delphi compatible version

```
{$IF CompilerVersion < 23} //pre-XE2
  NativeInt = integer;
{$IFEND}

function GetBitCount(num: NativeInt): integer;
asm
{$IFNDEF CPUX64}
  POPCNT    eax, num
{$ELSE CPUX64}
  POPCNT    rax, num
{$ENDIF CPUX64}
end;
```

Comment: That last one looks dodgy, will probably operate on a 32-bit value and store in a 64-bit one? Either zero out upper 32-bit or declare it as int64 ?

Comment: @Marco van de Voort Thanks, yes it is 32bit by default, but you can declare num as `NativeInt` or `Int64` or `UInt64` instead it works with all of tham. Corrected to Int64!

Comment: If you use a variable int size, you also need to ifdef the register in the popcnt line.

Comment: function GetBitCount(num: int64): int64;
asm
  POPCNT    rax, num
end;

Comment: sorry: 
function GetBitCount(num: int64): int64;
asm
  POPCNT    rax, num
end;         works fine, but got caught in testing by StrToInt() which doesn't work with 64bit ints... so delcared 

function StrToInt64( S: string): Int64;
var
  E: integer;
begin
  Val(S, Result, E);
  //if E <> 0 then ConvertErrorFmt(@SInvalidInteger, [S]);
end; which did the trick  - again thanks all

Comment: @user1423467: Added 32bit and 64bit Delphi compatible version

Comment: seems to need a type diective here{$IF CompilerVersion < 23} //pre-XE2
  type NativeInt = integer;
{$IFEND}  t

Comment: @user1423467: No, this compiler directive must be in the very beginning of unit in type section.