# Is there a Delphi equivalent for GCC's __builtin_popcountl, __builtin_clz, and __builtin_ctz?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, pascal, freepascal

I'm currently translating some C++ code into Delphi and came across the following GCC built-in functions:

- `__builtin_popcountl(x)`: Counts the number of set bits (1s) in the integer x.
- `__builtin_clz(x)`: Counts the number of leading zeros in the integer x.
- `__builtin_ctz(x)`: Counts the number of trailing zeros in the integer x.

Is there an equivalent function or a common way to achieve the same functionality in Delphi?

Comment: [See this for popcount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798051/popcnt-in-delphi-xe-xe2-64bit).  The general idea is to use assembly language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks unfortunatly i can not use ASM because i need a multi plateform solution :(

Comment: @zeus using assembly code doesn't preclude you from offering multi-platform support. It just means you will have to `{$IFDEF}` different assembly code for each platform that you want to target.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Delphi supports assembly only on Windows platforms.

Comment: These functions are all trivially implementable in plain C or Delphi. If you need a bit of speed, the reference to go to is [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: Assembler is not always practical because it can't be inlined leading to sub-par codegeneration. This is why FPC has added some intrinsics (popcnt ,  bsf/bsr and rol/ror). Rol/ror e.g. makes e.g. a MD5 assemblerless and thus portable, yet pretty close to optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do *Bit Checks*. The more idiomatic way to handle this is the built-in feature of `set of <Type>` as shown at:
[FreePascal `Set` documentation](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Set)
Which then will also result much more readable and maintainable.

The usage would then look like:

```pascal
type
  TFlag = (FLAG_A, FLAG_B, FLAG_C);
  TFlags = set of TFlag;

var
  Flags: TFlags;

// ...

  // check if Flags is empty
  if Flags = [] then
     Flags := [FLAG_A, FLAG_C];

  // check FLAG_A is set in flags variable
  if FLAG_A in Flags then 
    // ...
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with clz, ctz or popcount although some `Set` operations can utilize that. Those are very common in a lot of non-`Set` applications

Comment: Yes, this is not the **1-to-1 equivalent** to the C-functions but it is the more **idiomatic way** to achieve the same goal. Most likely some code needs to be rewritten to use this feature. But certainly the application will gain in **readability** and **maintainability** which is the strong feature of _Pascal_.